# How to use mongo-c-driver in VS2010

Tags: c++, c, mongodb, visual-studio-2010

I hava a problem in using mongo-c-driver in VS2010.

I used mongo-c-driver-1.2.0/VS2010/Win7-64bit;

Follow the steps in API document, I got four lib files.(I used cmake and VS2010 to build)

```
bson-1.0.lib  bson-static-1.0.lib  mongoc-1.0.lib mongoc-static-1.0.lib
```

And in my test program ,I put follow  #pragma comment:

```
#pragma comment(lib,"bson-1.0.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"mongoc-1.0.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"bson-static-1.0.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"mongoc-static-1.0.lib")
```

But it return some link error said

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mongoc_cleanup 
error LNK2019:unresolved external symbol _mongoc_client_destroy，
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mongoc_database_destroy，
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol  _mongoc_collection_destroy，
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _bson_free，
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol  _bson_destroy，
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol  _mongoc_collection_insert，
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol  _bson_as_json，
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mongoc_client_command_simple，
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _bcon_new，
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol  _bson_bcon_magic，
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol  _mongoc_client_get_collection，
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mongoc_client_get_database，
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol  _mongoc_client_new，
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol  _mongoc_init
```

Does anyone have idea about this problem. TAT.